# Activate WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have created a WordPress menu:

```
$menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu('MyMenu');
```

and added menu items to it successfully. They show up in Appearance-->Menus properly.

At the bottom of the menu list is "Menu Settings" with two check boxes. The first is "Automatically add..." and the second, "Primary Menu (currently set to:)".

I need the code to do what happens when the box is checked and I save the menu.

I am using Thesis-185 as the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Those checkboxes can be read using:

- `get_option('nav_menu_options')` for *"Automatically add..."*
- and `get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );` for *"Primary Menu (currently set to)"*

There's a hook for when the Nav Menus are updated (`wp_update_nav_menu`), but unfortunately [there's a bug on the system](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20275), as two identical hooks were created.

I've managed an ugly workaround to run only once:

```
add_action( 'load-nav-menus.php', function()
{
    if( isset( $_POST['save_menu'] ) )
    {
        global $my_hook_only_once;
        $my_hook_only_once = false;
        add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', function( $menu_id ) 
        {
            global $my_hook_only_once;
            if( $my_hook_only_once )
                return;
            $nav_options = get_option('nav_menu_options');
            $locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
            # Firephp logging
            // my_log( $nav_options['auto_add'], 'Auto add' );
            // my_log( $locations, 'Menu locations' );
            $my_hook_only_once = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Auto_add is not set (as I intend) and get_theme_mod returns the correct menu_id. The problem is that the Primary Menu checkbox keeps coming un-checked. I want to set it in my code so that I don't need to manually check this box.